# Windows Azure Pack - Maximum number of virtual machines per subscription id

Tags: azure-pack

For Windows Azure Pack setup for managing private cloud, what is the maximum number of virtual machines that can be created by a single user-role (i.e. per subscription-id) ?? I did not find any documentation giving these details. Can someone point to such details / documentation which gives these numbers ?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual networks per subscription?*

DEFAULT LIMIT
10

MAXIMUM LIMIT
100

- Each virtual network supports a single virtual network gateway.